# Display Settings stuck

Tags: display-resolution

I have searched the community.

I want to reset my display settings to defaults. I have one monitor, i adjusted windows sizes or something and now the control panel options to change back, they are outside of the edge of the panel I can see. And the window will not snap into place.

What is the terminal command to reset ALL windows settings?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer, but if you hold ALT & move the window (using your mouse), you can bring back the missing part into view....

I have an eee, and a lot of programs over-spill the screen edges so this is a useful trick!

I expect `xrandr` is the direct answer - look at the man page, you can set screens up manually.

Comment: TYVM.  I've since reinstalled. "xrandr" was pointless. I didn't know about the ALT-movement, I'll investigate. Thanks.